# Apache Commons FTPClient.listFiles

Tags: java, apache-commons, ftp-client

I am using [`org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient`](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) in one of my applications to work with a FTP server. I am able to `connect`, `login`, `pwd` and `cwd`. However, when I try to `list` the files it doesn't return the list of files in that directory, where I know for sure that there are files. I am using the method [`FTPFile[] listFiles()`](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#listFiles()), it returns an empty array of `FTPFile`.

Please find below the code snippet where I am trying this:

```
        String hostname = properties.getProperty("FTP_SERVER");
        String user = properties.getProperty("FTP_USER");
        String passwd = properties.getProperty("FTP_PASSWD");
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        client.connect(hostname);
        client.login(user, passwd);
        String reply = client.getStatus();
        System.out.println(reply);
        client.enterRemotePassiveMode();
        client.changeWorkingDirectory("/uploads");
        FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles();
        System.out.println(files.length);
        for (FTPFile file : files) {
            System.out.println(file.getName());
        }

        String[] fileNames = client.listNames();
        if (fileNames != null) {
            for (String file : fileNames) {
                System.out.println(file);
            }
        }
        client.disconnect();
```

Comment: I've encountered the same issue. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Commons Net FTPClient and listFiles()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712967/apache-commons-net-ftpclient-and-listfiles)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This seems like the same issue I had (and solved), see this answer:

[Apache Commons Net FTPClient and listFiles()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712967/apache-commons-net-ftpclient-and-listfiles/5183296#5183296)

Answer (score 6):

After I set the mode as `PASV` it is working fine now!
Thanks for all your efforts and suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

I added `client.enterLocalPassiveMode()` and it works:

```
client.connect("xxx.com");
boolean login = client.login("xxx", "xxx");
client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a silly suggestion... can you do a listing on the /uploads folder using a normal FTP client. I ask this because some FTP servers are setup to not display the listing of an upload folder.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the listing works in other programs.  If so, one possibility is that the file listing isn't being parsed correctly.  You can try explicitly specifying the parser to use with [initiateListParsing](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#initiateListParsing%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Yes -- for example, the FTPFileListParser implentation that's passed to listFilemight assume lines must be a certain length, then miss all the files on a server with a different implementation of the LIST command.

Answer (score 1):

I had to same problem and it turned out to be that it couldn't parse what the server was returning for a file listing.  I this line after connecting to the ftp server ftpClient.setParserFactory(new MyFTPFileEntryParserFactory());

```
public class MyFTPFileEntryParserFactory implements FTPFileEntryParserFactory {
private final static FTPFileEntryParser parser = new UnixFTPEntryParser() {
    @Override public FTPFile parseFTPEntry(String entry) {
        FTPFile ftpFile = new FTPFile();
        ftpFile.setTimestamp(getCalendar(entry));
        ftpFile.setSize(get(entry));
        ftpFile.setName(getName(entry));
        return ftpFile;
    }
};

@Override public FTPFileEntryParser createFileEntryParser(FTPClientConfig config) throws ParserInitializationException {
    return parser;
}

@Override public FTPFileEntryParser createFileEntryParser(String key) throws ParserInitializationException {
    return parser;
}
```

}

Comment: Similarly, the code I was looking at called a custom parser every time instead of allowing the auto-detect parser when the system type was normal Unix.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, on top of applying **enterLocalPassiveMode** and indicating correct operation system, I also need to set **UnparseableEntries** to true to make the listFile method work.

```
FTPClientConfig conf = new FTPClientConfig(FTPClientConfig.SYST_UNIX);
conf.setUnparseableEntries(true);
f.configure(conf);
boolean isLoginSuccess = client.login(username, password);
```