# Issue with org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient listFiles()

Tags: java, apache-commons, ftp-client

The `listFiles()` method of `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` works fine with Filezilla server on 127.0.0.1 but returns `null` on the root directory of public FTP servers such as belnet.be.

There is an identical question on the link below but `enterRemotePassiveMode()` doesn't seem to help.
[Apache Commons FTPClient.listFiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339855/apache-commons-ftpclient-listfiles)

Could it be an issue with list parsing? If so, how can go about solving this?

Edit: Here's a directory cache dump:

FileZilla Directory Cache Dump

Dumping 1 cached directories

```
Entry 1:
Path: /
Server: anonymous@ftp.belnet.be:21, type: 4096
Directory contains 7 items:
  lrw-r--r-- ftp ftp      D          28      2009-06-17   debian
  lrw-r--r-- ftp ftp      D          31      2009-06-17   debian-cd
  -rw-r--r-- ftp ftp                  0 2010-03-04 13:30  keepalive.txt
  drwxr-xr-x ftp ftp      D        4096 2010-02-18 14:22  mirror
  lrw-r--r-- ftp ftp      D           6      2009-06-17   mirrors
  drwxr-xr-x ftp ftp      D        4096      2009-06-23   packages
  lrw-r--r-- ftp ftp      D           1      2009-06-17   pub
```

Here's my code using a wrapper I've made (testing inside the wrapper produces the same results):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    FTPUtils ftpUtils = new FTPUtils();
    String ftpURL = "ftp.belnet.be";
    Connection connection = ftpUtils.getFTPClientManager().getConnection( ftpURL );

    if( connection == null ){
        System.out.println( "Could not connect" );
        return; 
    }

    FTPClientManager manager = connection.getFptClientManager();
    FTPClient client = manager.getClient();

    try {
        client.enterRemotePassiveMode();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if( connection != null ){
        System.out.println( "Connected to FTP" );
        connection.login("Anonymous", "Anonymous");
        if( connection.isLoggedIn() ){
            System.out.println( "Login successful" );
            LoggedInManager loggedin = connection.getLoggedInManager(); 
            System.out.println( loggedin );
            String[] fileList = loggedin.getFileList();

            System.out.println( loggedin.getWorkingDirectory() );

            if( fileList == null || fileList.length == 0 )
                System.out.println( "No files found" );
            else{
                for (String name : fileList ) {
                    System.out.println( name );
                }
            }

            connection.disconnect();

            if( connection.isDisconnected() )
                System.out.println( "Disconnection successful" );
            else
                System.out.println( "Error disconnecting" );
        }else{
            System.out.println( "Unable to login" );
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println( "Could not connect" );
    }
}
```

Produces this output:

```
Connected to FTP
Login succesful
utils.ftp.FTPClientManager$Connection$LoggedInManager@156ee8e
null
No files found
Disconnection successful
```

Inside the wrapper (attempted using both `listNames()` and `listFiles()` ):

```
        public String[] getFileList() {
            String[] fileList = null;
            FTPFile[] ftpFiles = null;

            try {
                ftpFiles = client.listFiles();
                //fileList = client.listNames();
                //System.out.println( client.listNames() );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }

            fileList = new String[ ftpFiles.length ];

            for( int i = 0; i < ftpFiles.length; i++ ){
                fileList[ i ] = ftpFiles[ i ].getName();
            }

            return fileList;
        }
```

As for FTPClient, it is handled as follows:

```
public class FTPUtils {

private FTPClientManager clientManager;

public FTPClientManager getFTPClientManager(){
    clientManager = new FTPClientManager();
    clientManager.setClient( new FTPClient() );

    return clientManager;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each FTP server has a different file list layout (yes, it's not part of the FTP standard, it's dumb), and so you have to use the correct `FTPFileEntryParser`, either by specifying it manually, or allowing CommonsFTP to auto-detect it.

Auto-detection usually works fine, but sometimes it doesn't, and you have to specify it explicitly, e.g.

```
FTPClientConfig conf = new FTPClientConfig(FTPClientConfig.SYST_UNIX);

FTPClient client = FTPClient();
client.configure(conf);
```

This explicitly sets the expected FTP server type to UNIX.  Try the various types, see how it goes. I tried finding out myself, but `ftp.belnet.be` is refusing my connections :(

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it's possible to get the raw list output before it's parsed?

Also, Belnet (belgian research network) might be limited to belgian ips. You can try ftp://c64.rulez.org.

Comment: @James: You could, I suppose, provide your own implementation of `FTPFileEntryParser`

Comment: by the way the default is Unix if you see the constructor it is like this  public FTPClientConfig()
    {
        this("UNIX");
    }

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried checking that you can list the files using normal FTP client?  (For some reason, I cannot even connect to the FTP port of "belnet.be".)

**EDIT**

According to the javadoc for [listFiles()](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#listFiles()), the parsing is done using the [FTPFileEntryParser](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPFileEntryParser.html) instance provided by the parser factory.  You probably need to figure out which of the parsers matches the FTP server's LIST output and configure the factory accordingly.

Comment: Yes. The files on belnet.be show up fine in FileZilla. A few folders in the root appear to be shortcuts or links. I don't know if that could be a problem. I've added a dump of the directory listing.

Comment: Thanks. Also, the ftp address is ftp.belnet.be.

Answer (score 1):

There was a parsing issue in earlier version of apache-Commons-net , the **SYST** command which returns the server type when **returns null** ( abruptly ) was not handled in parsingException . Try using the **latest jar** of apache-commons-net it may solve your problem.