# Apache FTPClient listFiles() vs listFileNames()

Tags: java, apache, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I am using apache-commons-net 3.4 and i found a strange issue i cant explain. I want to get the `FTPFile` entries of an directory but when i use `FTPClient#listFiles()` an empty array is returned, but `FTPClient#listNames()` list all entries.

```
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

    client.connect("192.168.1.4");
    client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    client.login("ftpuser", "ftpuser");

    System.out.println( client.listFiles("/").length); // prints 0
    System.out.println( client.listNames("/").length); // prints 21
```

What is going on here how to use `listFiles()` correct ?

Related questions that didn't answer my question:

- [Apache Commons Net FTPClient and listFiles()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712967/apache-commons-net-ftpclient-and-listfiles)
- [Issue with org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient listFiles()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576647/issue-with-org-apache-commons-net-ftp-ftpclient-listfiles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic could help you make `listFiles` work :

[FTPClient.listFiles not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790074/ftpclient-listfiles-not-working)

From the documentation of `FtpClient`, the two methods don't work in the same way :

> **listFiles**(String pathname) Using the *default system autodetect*
>   *mechanism*, obtain a list of file information for the current working directory or for just a single file.This information is obtained
>   through the *LIST command*.
>
> **listNames**(String pathname) Obtain a list of filenames in a directory
>   (or just the name of a given file, which is not particularly useful).This information is obtained through *the NLST command*.