# Apache Commons Net FTPClient and listFiles()

Tags: java, apache-commons, ftp-client

Can anyone explain me what's wrong with the following code? I tried different hosts, FTPClientConfigs, it's properly accessible via firefox/filezilla... The problem is I always get empty filelist without any exceptions (files.length == 0). I use commons-net-2.1.jar installed with Maven.

```
    FTPClientConfig config = new FTPClientConfig(FTPClientConfig.SYST_L8);

    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    client.configure(config);

    client.connect("c64.rulez.org");
    client.login("anonymous", "anonymous");
    client.enterRemotePassiveMode();

    FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles();
    Assert.assertTrue(files.length > 0);
```

Comment: Any error message? Not sure what your problem is!

Comment: The problem is I always get empty filelist without any exceptions (files.length == 0). Question is updated.

Comment: It works fine on my FTP server, except that I don't call client.configure(...)

Comment: I tried also ftp.belnet.be / ftp.ccc.uba.ar and some private ftp servers and can't get it to work (even without client.configure)... I also tried to disable windows firewall and antivirus... Can you share some working ftp host?

Comment: ftp4j basic example works properly, but I would like to know what's wrong with my commons-net code...

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Found it!

The thing is you want to ***enter passive mode after you connect, but before you log in***. 
Your code returns nothing for me, but this works for me:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

public class BasicFTP {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        client.connect("c64.rulez.org");
        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        client.login("anonymous", "");
        FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles("/pub");
        for (FTPFile file : files) {
            System.out.println(file.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Gives me this output:

```
c128
c64
c64.hu
incoming
plus4
```

Comment: (Regarding the BTW comment: `Assert.assertTrue` is from JUnit or TestNG; Java's assert would simply be `assert`. Anyway, I guess the point was just to illustrate desired outcome to readers of the question.)

Comment: @Jonik Oh, that's right. I wasn't paying attention. I removed that bit.

Comment: there are localpassive remotepassive, localactive, remoteactive i tried them one after another, and yeh localpassive worked

Comment: Thanks a ton my dear friend, i searched all the website but unable to find any solution to this issue. You code saved me! Just cool

Answer (score 14):

Only using `enterLocalPassiveMode()` did not work for me.

I used following code, which worked.

```
    ftpsClient.execPBSZ(0);
    ftpsClient.execPROT("P");
    ftpsClient.type(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

Complete example is as below,

```
    FTPSClient ftpsClient = new FTPSClient();        

    ftpsClient.connect("Host", 21);

    ftpsClient.login("user", "pass");

    ftpsClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

    ftpsClient.execPBSZ(0);
    ftpsClient.execPROT("P");
    ftpsClient.type(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

    FTPFile[] files = ftpsClient.listFiles();

    for (FTPFile file : files) {
        System.out.println(file.getName());
    }
```

Comment: Cannot find methods: ftpClient.execPBSZ(0);
    ftpClient.execPROT("P")

Comment: Are you using FTPClient or FTPSClient? Those methods only exist in FTPSClient.

Answer (score 3):

usually the annonymous user doesn't need a password, try

```
client.login("anonymous", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when I used `ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode()` just before calling `ftpClient.listFiles()`.
Here is the full code:

```
                final List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    String[] f = null;
                    if (parentDir.isEmpty()) {
                        f = ftpClient.listNames();
                    }else{
                        f = ftpClient.listNames(parentDir);
                    }
                    for (String s :f ) {
                        files.add(s);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    postError(e.getMessage()!= null?e.getMessage():e.toString());
                }
```