# FTPClient.listFiles() returns zero records

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I can connect to remote FTP server on AS400 box.

When i try to get the list of files, I get no files. The same piece of code gives me records when I connect to remote FTP server which is on windows.

I tried the following things,

```
FTPFile [] files = ftpClient.listFiles(); // Assuming I am already in the working directory.
OR
FTPFile [] files = ftpClient.listFiles(remoteFolder);
```

I have tried setting the filetype as both binary and ascii, nothing works for AS400 ftp server.

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712967/apache-commons-net-ftpclient-and-listfiles

Comment: When I used commons-net-3.2.jar, the issue got resolved. Earlier I was using commons-net-1.4.1.jar.