# FTPClient.listFiles not working

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons, ftp-client, ftplib

I am trying to list all the files under a specific directory in a ftp server.

```
FTPFile[] subFiles = ftpClient.listFiles("directory");
```

Although the directory is a valid one , but the code gets stuck while calling listFiles , what may be the reason. ? Further i would like to mention that a seperate netbeans project accessing the same FTP server is working fine with the same code , but a maven project is having the problem.
please help.

Comment: Eich's answer worked for me. And I deeply suspect you are doing something wrong Raja as you stated 1.4.1 was the current version but that version was released in 2005, 3.2 was the current version the day of your comment.

Answer (score 12):

Try to use [`passive mode`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#enterLocalPassiveMode%28%29). I assume that you are using the newest [commons net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) library (you didn't write which lib you are using).

---

Next approach, try to change the file list layout. The commons lib uses auto-detection but in some cases this doesn't work. You can change (and test) another file list layout as followed:

```
FTPClientConfig configuration = new FTPClientConfig(FTPClientConfig.TEST_YOURSELF);

FTPClient yourClient = FTPClient(...);
client.configure(conf);
```

Comment: Yes , I am using passive mode before login . The apache commons net is version 1.4.1 , which is the latest one.

Comment: Can you access (and list files) with your ftp software (like [filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org//))? Have you also tried `listFiles("/directory")`?

Comment: Using filezilla I can see the files , and yes in ftpClient.listFiles("directory") , i have tried all possible cases , have taken the root path ("/") and have also tried with a folder inside the root ftp directory ( "/AnyFolder").

Comment: I've edited my answer, maybe if you change the file list layout you can get the list of files.

Comment: **This is what i did..still not working** 
`System.out.println("Enter Testing..");` `ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode(); FTPClientConfig conf = new` `FTPClientConfig(FTPClientConfig.SYST_UNIX);` `conf.setServerLanguageCode("fr"); ftpClient.configure(conf);` `FTPFile[] subFiles = ftpClient.listFiles("/");` `System.out.println("Exit Testing");`

Comment: Where is your `ftpClient.login(...)`?

Comment: The initial login configuration has been done in a seperate function , the listing one was being called therein , using ftpClient as one of the parameters.

Comment: Modified the ques
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809593/ftp-connection-timed-out-421-when-running-project-via-maven

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27559/discussion-between-raja-and-eich)

Comment: I just added a call to enterLocalPassiveMode after connect and it solved my problem. I'm using commons-net 3.3.

Comment: Same problem here.  I had enterLocalPassiveMode() call BEFORE connect(), while it was supposed to be AFTER.  thanks

Answer (score 4):

To add to above answers the enterLocalPassiveMode() method should be called after connect() and before login(). Any other way I couldn't get mine to work. This testing was based on another answer as specified here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5183296/11971304

```
            client.connect(host, port);
            client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            if (!client.login(username, password)) {
                throw new LoginException("wrong credentials");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, with same source code, it's running fine when I run it via IDE (IntelliJ), but when run in server, it always return no file while trying to call `ftpClient.listFiles()`

My fix is active `Local Passive Mode` after connect to FTP server.

```
ftpClient.connect("FTP_server_address");
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```