# FTP client - listfiles

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I am unable to get the exact file list using FTPClient. Sample code as below :

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
client.connect("x.x.x.x");
client.login("abcd", "abcd");
FTPFile[] ftpFiles = client.listFiles();
for (FTPFile ftpFile : ftpFiles) {
   System.out.println("FTPFile: " + ftpFile.getName());
}
```

I tried to set to PASV mode using enterLocalPassiveMode()/enterRemotePassiveMode()/pasv(). But, it doesnt work.

Please also check [Apache Commons FTPClient.listFiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339855/apache-commons-ftpclient-listfiles) ..

Thank you

Comment: You'll need to be more descriptive about the problem. What happens when you run the code? Can you login? Do you get some of the data? None of it?

Comment: Please explain, what you *expect* and what you currently *observe* (iaw - what's missing on your result list)

Comment: Hi Andreas, I am able to login and view the list of files but they are incomplete eg. if there are 5 files, I am able to view only couple of them.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `files` is, but you're getting the results of `client.listFiles` in `ftpFiles`, and not in `files`. Then in your `for` loop you go over `files`.

Comment: Sorry typoerror.. But, my problem is incomplete file list. eg. if "ls" views me 4 files, using listfiles() I get a result of 1/2 files only.

Comment: Did you try several folders? Maybe the problem is not in your code. What files are missing? Anything special about them?

Comment: The files are normal txt files with different file extn. When I use other FTP client programs it displays all the files properly. But my code displays only few of them.

Comment: Can you do the same test on a different folder with different files?

Comment: Yes I tried with another folder .. It is unpredictable sometimes lists exact all files sometimes it doesnt.. BTW one observation is fewer files it lists properly but if the directory contains more than 20 or so.. some files are missing then.

Comment: An anonymous user suggested _use ftpclient.listnames then you can get names of the files in the server_

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
String[] fileFtp = client.listNames();//if it is directory. then list of file names

//download file
for (int i =0;i<fileFtp.length;i++) {

   String fileName = fileFtp[i];

   OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("local temp file name"));

   if (!client.retrieveFile(fileName, out)) {       
        sysout("Could not download the file. "+ fileName);
    } else {
        sysout("Downloaded file @ : "+localFileName);   
    }       
}
```

This should work.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this work even with files that have spaces in filename?